# Replacing the router of Symfony2 framework by a new one

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, symfony-components

Since roughly 2 years, I do use a **special routing mechanism**, which **strongly protects the control flow** of web applications.

Now, I'd like to implement this routing mechanism based on the [Symfony2 framework](http://symfony.com) (to bring it to attention of more developers).

I'm in general aware of the concept of a [Symfony2 component](http://symfony.com/components).

**But would a new router be a [Symfony2 component](http://symfony.com/components) anyway? Or do I need to search for another integration point?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you need to implement a custom router in Symfony which enhance your routing mechanism; so please take a look at [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic_customize.html] and this link [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html] hopefully it helps

Comment: Hey, folks, why not write a comment and give hints how to improve my post - instead of silently down voting